# What is the real difference between @PostMapping and @PutMapping in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to update an entity from my Oracle database using a Spring RestController. Whether I use PostMapping or PutMapping on my controller method, the effect is the same on the entity, only the field I want to update gets updated and everything is fine.
What is the real difference between the two request methods? Is it only for a clearer description on the controller method?

Update : it seems even if I use a GetMapping, my entity updates correctly. I am really starting to think that the request is getting handled in the Service layer and the request annotation is only for a clearer view on the controller method, but I could be wrong. Really curious for an explanation. Thank you!

Thank you!

Comment: One allows accepting HTTP POST request, the other one allows accepting HTTP PUT requests. None of them has anything to do with how entities are saved. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html

Comment: this makes sense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PUT vs. POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)